# Не работает display: flex; но блоки указал верно

Tags: html, css

Делаю сайт по уроку блоки идут вертикально сверху вниз, вснем все блоки в отдельный `div` и указал `displey flex`, но ничего не меняется, так же пробовал менять цвет блоков он меняется то есть в `div` внес я верно, не понимаю в чем проблема

```css
.cards-holder {
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 40px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: 349px;
}

.card-image {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card-title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card-desc {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="conteiner">
  <div class="cards-holder">
    <div class="cards">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img class="card-image" src="card-img.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="card-title">Магическая Атмосфера</div>

        <div class="card-desc">
          В нашем заведении царит магическая атмосфера наполненная вкусными ароматами
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img class="card-image" src="card-img.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="card-title">Магическая Атмосфера</div>

        <div class="card-desc">
          В нашем заведении царит магическая атмосфера наполненная вкусными ароматами
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img class="card-image" src="card-img.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="card-title">Магическая Атмосфера</div>

        <div class="card-desc">
          В нашем заведении царит магическая атмосфера наполненная вкусными ароматами
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: вот так выглядит а должно быть горизонтально]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно задать `display: flex` блоку с классом `.cards`, по дефолту дочерние блоки будут размещены горизонтально

Comment: Теперь не работает justify-content пытаюсь выставить его на центр дабы выставить блоки ровно

Comment: Для этого необходимо задать ширину блоку с классом `.cards` в 100%, либо избавиться от лишней обертки с классом `.cards-holder`, если она не планируется использоваться в будущем